# PHP submit inside loop table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a foreach loop that outputs my products in a table. Code shown below:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_2">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th style="width: 9%;"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($inputs as $package){
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<tr>
<td><?php echo $package->id; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $package->name; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity for <?php echo $package->name; ?>" class="form-control"></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn blue"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> submit</button></td>
</tr>
</form>
<?php }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Okay i now need to create something to insert the fields into a mysql table. But how do i get `$package->id, $package->name`, they are just echo's? I need it inserted into this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_packages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `worker` varchar(265) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Code for submit 1.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$productid = $_POST['id'];
$productname = $_POST['name'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$worker = $user['name'];
$workerid = $user['id'];
$result = $user->add_packages($productid,$productname,$quantity,$worker,$workerid);
}
```

Print_r($_POST['package'])

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Maxizoo Spåner 5 kg ) [2] => Array ( [quantity] => ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 ) [4] => Array ( [name] => Minihemp 4 kg. ) [5] => Array ( [quantity] => ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 5 ) [7] => Array ( [name] => Maxizoo Hø 2 kg. ) [8] => Array ( [quantity] => 2 ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 6 ) [10] => Array ( [name] => Maxizoo Halm 2 kg ) [11] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 ) )
```

UPDATE:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

foreach ($_POST['package'] as $p){

    $productid = $p['id'];
    $productname = $p['name'];
    $quantity = $p['quantity'];

    }

$worker = $user['name'];
$workerid = $user['id'];
$result = $user->add_packages($productid,$productname,$quantity,$worker,$workerid);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send them with form, for example using hidden inputs.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $package->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $package->name; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity for <?php echo $package->name; ?>" class="form-control"></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="hidden" name="package_name" value="<?php echo $package->name; ?>"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="package_id" value="<?php echo $package->id; ?>"> 
                ^^
                <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn blue"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Than, you use `TR`s and `TD`s, they should be in a table only, so I've added a table too.

Comment: Is it then possible to submit all on same time, so it sends the insert command for each?

Comment: Sure, if you want to send to database more packages, use arrays in `name` attributes. First package hidden inputs will have `name="package[0][name]", name="package[0][id]"`, for the second one `name="package[1][name]", name="package[1][id]"`, etc. In PHP it will be in array `$_POST['package']`, try that or see using `print_r`

Comment: Can you take a look on the new code i added, doesn't really know how to do it. The add_packages function just insert.. The code i added, only work with 1 product, not the whole loop

Comment: Sure, you don't use arrays as I wrote you above.

Comment: I tried `print_r($_POST['package'])`, but that just printed the array for one product, and i get add the new names you sent..

Comment: And gave you all products in one `form`? Using `submit` input/button you send only the form which is parent of this submit button. If you need to send more product, put them inside one form (with one or more submit buttons, it doesn't matter).

Comment: Yes, i start the form before the loop. But how can i change `name="package[0][name]" - name="package[1][name]"` in the loop, i think thats the problem. `<input type="hidden" name="package[0][id]" value="<?php echo $package->id; ?>">`

Comment: Before loop set `$i = 0;`, into `name`s put `$i` instead of fixed `0` or `1` and before foreach's `}` increase `$i` using `$i++;`

Comment: Okay, that works now! However, now i just need the right variables for the insert. What is the post variables now? It isn't $_POST['id'] etc..

Comment: Everything what you need you can see in `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: I added the array to the main post, but i dont get it. If i do: `$_POST['id']` it says `Undefined index: id`

Comment: Look, what `print_r` returns. `$_POST['package'][0]['name'], $_POST['package'][0]['id'], $_POST['package'][1]['name']`, etc. `foreach ($_POST['package'] as $p)`, in first loop `$p['name']`, `$p['id']` contains name and ID of 1st product, in the second loop in the same variables are information for the second one product etc.

Comment: Sorry, im lost. Look last update would that work, or do i have to move the loop?